# Find Inverse Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, fourier-motzkin

Find the inverse Fourier Transform of

$$ 
{
F(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi(a+j\omega)^2} 
\
}
$$
using the convolution theorem. Hint: the Fourier Transform of $e^{-at} u(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(a+j\omega)}  $

Answer (score 0):

The convolution theorem gives us:
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\mathcal{F}(f)\cdot\mathcal{F}(g)]= f*g$$

From the hint:
$$F(\omega) = \mathcal{F}(e^{-at}u(t))\cdot\mathcal{F}(e^{-at}u(t))$$
and you seek $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[F(\omega)]$.

Can you finish it?

Comment: No I can not finish it

Comment: Use the convolution theorem to get: $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[F(\omega)] = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\mathcal{F}(e^{-at}u(t))\cdot\mathcal{F}(e^{-at}u(t))] = (e^{-at}u(t))*(e^{-at}u(t))$
And the convolution is then:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a(t-\tau)}u(t-\tau)e^{-a\tau}u(\tau)d\tau$

Does this help?